# replacing strings in a configuration file with shell scripting

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I have a configuration file with fields separated by semicolons `;`. Something like:

```
user@raspberrypi /home/pi $ cat file  
string11;string12;string13;
string21;string22;string23;
string31;string32;string33;
```

I can get the strings I need with awk:

```
user@raspberrypi /home/pi $ cat file | grep 21 | awk -F ";" '{print $2}' 
string22
```

And I'd like to change `string22` to `hello_world` via a script.

Any idea how to do it? I think it should be with `sed` but I have no idea how.

Comment: +1... Good first question, sample input, required output and attempt at a solution. Keep posting! Good luck to all.

Answer (score 2):

First drop the useless use of `cat` and `grep` so:

```
$ cat file | grep 21 | awk -F';' '{print $2}'
```

Becomes:

```
$ awk -F';' '/21/{print $2}' file
```

To change this value you would do:

```
$ awk '/21/{$2="hello_world"}1' FS=';' OFS=';' file
```

To store the changes back to the file:

```
$ awk '/21/{$2="hello_world"}1' FS=';' OFS=';' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

However if all you want to do is replace `string22` with `hello_world` I would suggest using `sed` instead:

```
$ sed 's/string22;/hello_world;/g' file
```

With `sed` you can use the `-i` option to store the changes back to the file:

```
$ sed -i 's/string22;/hello_world;/g' file
```

Comment: And to restrict sed to focus on the requested line: `sed -i '/21/s/...,`

Comment: And might be safer to use `\<string22\>` to ensure `gstring22` doesn't get changed (for `sed` solution).

Answer (score 2):

I prefer [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) better than [sed](/questions/tagged/sed). Here a one-liner that modifies the file in-place.

```
perl -i -F';' -lane '
    BEGIN { $" = q|;| } 
    if ( m/21/ ) { $F[1] = q|hello_world| }; 
    print qq|@F|
' infile
```

Use `-i.bak` instead of `-i` to create a backup file with `.bak` as suffix.

It yields:

```
string11;string12;string13
string21;hello_world;string23
string31;string32;string33
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though we can do this in awkeasily  as Sudo suggested i prefer perl since it does inline replacement.

```
perl -pe 's/(^[^\;]*;)[^\;]*(;.*)/$1hello_world$2/g if(/21/)' your_file
```

for in line just add an i

```
perl -pi -e 's/(^[^\;]*;)[^\;]*(;.*)/$1hello_world$2/g if(/21/)' your_file
```

Tested below:

```
> perl -pe 's/(^[^\;]*;)[^\;]*(;.*)/$1"hello_world"$2/g if(/21/)' temp
string11;string12;string13;
string21;"hello_world";string23;
string31;string32;string33;
> perl -pe 's/(^[^\;]*;)[^\;]*(;.*)/$1hello_world$2/g if(/21/)' temp
string11;string12;string13;
string21;hello_world;string23;
string31;string32;string33;
>
```